# don't finish gradle build running

Tags: android, gradle, build

I had an Android project that transferred all the code and resources and files to a new project! But build gradle is still being processed when I want to run the project and apparently never wants to finish. My project has no errors..
Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

i set http proxy to none .
i cleaned project and tried again .
i invalid caches/restart and tried again.
But none of these ways helped..

I have to close the android studio from Task Manager. And then delete the contents of the crash folder from gradle  and invalid caches/restart and clean project and after that, I will run the program, and with any error, all these things should be done

this is image link    https://i.stack.imgur.com/EElr0.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem Solved when i install new windows and new android studio ...
There may be a problem with my previous SDK